# Check for opened Browser using WatiN

Tags: watin

I want to check if an IE is already opened or not

```
If IE is opened so i.e. Goto("WWW.GOOGLE.COM");
else open new IE and goto Yahoo.com
```

for example:

```
 br = new WatiN.Core.IE(@textBox1.Text);
```

then when I press a button I want to check if IE is opened or not and perform the previous scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
IE.Exists(Find.ByUrl("Yahoo.com"));
```

In WatiN 2.0 RC1 this will be:

```
Browser.Exists<IE>(Find.ByUrl("Yahoo.com"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
but I want to check for the opened IE instances by (br) but
 IE.Exists(Find.ByUrl("Yahoo.com"));
will return true also if there is an IE instance opened manually and has the same URL.

Comment: In that case, maybe this code/idea might help http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2009/03/reusing-ie-instance-in-vs-test.html